# Extra dimension to MaxPool1D layer from Conv1D layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm very new to Tensorflow (this is my first project using it), and I don't really understand how input shapes work. I am trying to train a CNN-LSTM on a set of financial time series data.

For my use case, I have a `tf.keras.data.DataLoader` object which is meant to serve batches of training data to the model.

One training instance corresponds to the price history over the last 30 days, and hence should have shape `(30,)`.

running the following code:

```
for x, y in train_ds:
    print(x, y)
    print(x.shape)
    break
```

I get that `x.shape` is `(4, 30)`, where the `Dataset` object I have defined serves training instances in batches of 4.

Here is my code:

```
# driver code for experiments
import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import layers

WIDTH = 30
BATCH_SIZE = 4

# load datasets (prepended with 'n' for 'normalized' )

nXtrain = np.load('cad_90s_nXtrain.npy')
nytrain = np.load('cad_90s_nytrain.npy')
nXval = np.load('cad_90s_nXval.npy')
nyval = np.load('cad_90s_nyval.npy')
nXtest = np.load('cad_90s_nXtest.npy')
nytest = np.load('cad_90s_nytest.npy')

# instantiate tensorflow Datasets
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((nXtrain, nytrain)).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
val_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((nXval, nyval)).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((nXtest, nytest)).batch(BATCH_SIZE)


input_shape = (BATCH_SIZE, WIDTH, 1 )

testnet = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.InputLayer(input_shape=input_shape),
    layers.Conv1D(filters=32,
                  kernel_size=3,
                  activation='tanh',
                  padding='same',
                  strides=1),
    layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=2,
                     padding='same'),
    layers.ReLU(),
    layers.LSTM(units=64, dropout=0.2, activation='tanh'),
    layers.Dense(units=1)
])

testnet.build()
testnet.summary()
```

with accompanying error message:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "max_pooling1d" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 4, 30, 32)
```

I don't understand what's going on--why is there an extra dimension coming out of the `Conv1D` layer? I mean, should the output of 1-D convolution not simply be
`(BATCH_SIZE, WIDTH, 32)` (padding was set to `'same'`)?

I apologize if this is addressed in the documentation, but I have been looking everywhere for an answer and I can't seem to fix this problem. I would really appreciate some help here.

Thanks!

Comment: `input` shape should not include the batch dimension; only use `(WIDTH, 1)`. Is this addressed in the documentation? I'm not actually sure if this is explicitely presented anywhere. Definitely one of the most common problems for newcomers.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem--I was sure I had tried that!

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @xdurch0, tf.keras.layers.InputLayer does not take Batch_size.

> input_shape:  Shape tuple (not including the batch axis), or TensorShape
> instance (not including the batch axis).

For information refer this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/InputLayer)

**Working sample code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
input_shape = (4, 1)
x = tf.random.normal(input_shape)
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=32,
                  kernel_size=3,
                  activation='tanh',
                  padding='same',
                  strides=1),)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=2,
                     padding='same'))

output = model(x)
```

**Output**

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 1, 32), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[ 0.4607179 ,  0.15637583, -0.5004345 , -0.07796285,
          0.30203223,  0.45201266,  0.01206997,  0.49042067,
          0.190878  , -0.06044334,  0.35961443, -0.2021137 ,
         -0.49953443, -0.03703883,  0.31947324,  0.10558284,
         -0.4071377 , -0.17169577,  0.41974816,  0.35714787,
         -0.1540432 ,  0.16283943, -0.38012537,  0.08710621,
          0.5129782 , -0.38887107,  0.06570872,  0.12256396,
         -0.2707871 ,  0.31438676,  0.08643996,  0.02944363]],

       [[ 0.15212363,  0.04848025, -0.16761488, -0.024035  ,
          0.09564026,  0.1488167 ,  0.00371435,  0.16364299,
          0.05939662, -0.01862026,  0.11532419, -0.06297952,
         -0.16725594, -0.01140236,  0.10152339,  0.03260009,
         -0.13221109, -0.05331242,  0.13680711,  0.11446481,
         -0.04774643,  0.05051624, -0.12253318,  0.02686608,
          0.17265812, -0.12564273,  0.02024639,  0.03788798,
         -0.08525081,  0.09980103,  0.02665966,  0.00906281]],

       [[-0.15694636, -0.05004002,  0.17290986,  0.02480924,
         -0.09870265, -0.15353796, -0.00383405, -0.16881739,
         -0.06130603,  0.01922018, -0.11900602,  0.06500347,
          0.17254004,  0.01176979, -0.1047715 , -0.03364989,
          0.13641952,  0.05502706, -0.14115801, -0.11811972,
          0.04928267, -0.05214129,  0.1264404 , -0.02773144,
         -0.17810565,  0.12964691, -0.02089867, -0.03910775,
          0.08798415, -0.1029948 , -0.02751837, -0.00935485]],

       [[ 0.25630587,  0.08277144, -0.281522  , -0.04108214,
          0.16258071,  0.25089246,  0.0063511 ,  0.27507976,
          0.10133278, -0.03183164,  0.19552334, -0.10741517,
         -0.28094047, -0.01949524,  0.17245385,  0.05570482,
         -0.22355829, -0.09099286,  0.2311481 ,  0.19409074,
         -0.08152226,  0.0862364 , -0.20751894,  0.04591698,
          0.28967807, -0.21268068,  0.03461014,  0.06472494,
         -0.14509352,  0.16956565,  0.04556449,  0.01549565]]],
      dtype=float32)>
```